# function not recognizing args and kwargs

Tags: python, python-2.7, args, keyword-argument

I am trying to define a function like so:

```
def get_event_stats(elengths, einds, *args, **kwargs):

    master_list = []

    if avg:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...
    if tot:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...

    return master_list
```

I would like elengths and einds to be fixed positional args (these are just arrays of ints). I am trying to use the function by passing it a variable length list of arrays as *args and some **kwargs, in this example two (avg and tot), but potentially more, for example,

```
avg_event_time = get_event_stats(event_lengths, eventInds, *alist, avg=True, tot=False)
```

where

```
alist = [time, counts]
```

and my kwargs are avg and tot, which are given the value of True and False respectively. Regardless of how I've tried to implement this function, I get some kind of error. What am I missing here in the correct usage of *args and **kwargs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant that `avg` and `tot` should be passed in as keyword args, like in your example `get_event_stats(..., avg=True, tot=False)` then they are populated in `kwargs`. You can look them up in the `kwargs` dict using a key lookup (like `kwargs['avg']`.

However if they are not present at all, then that will give a key error, so use it with the `dict.get()` method: `kwargs.get('avg')` which returns `None` if it is not present, which is boolean `False`. Or use `kwargs.get('avg', False)` if you explicitly want a `False` if it's not present.

```
def get_event_stats(elengths, einds, *args, **kwargs):

    master_list = []

    if kwargs.get('avg'):
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...
    if kwargs.get('tot'):
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...

    return master_list
```

Answer (score 3):

`**kwargs` creates a `dict`, it doesn't inject arbitrary names into your local namespace. If you want to look for whether a particular keyword was passed, you can't test `if avg:` (there is no variable named `avg`), you need to check if `avg` is in the `dict`, e.g. `if 'avg' in kwargs:`, or to check both existence and "truthiness", so passing `avg=False` is equivalent to not passing it at all, test `if kwargs.get('avg'):` (using `kwargs.get('avg')` ensures no exception is thrown if `avg` wasn't passed at all, unlike `if kwargs['avg']:`).

Note: You should really move to Python 3 if at all possible. It makes writing this function much more obvious and clean, as you could avoid the need for `kwargs` completely, and verify no unrecognized keyword arguments were passed by just defining the function as:

```
def get_event_stats(elengths, einds, *args, avg=False, tot=False):
    master_list = []

    if avg:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...
    if tot:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...

    return master_list
```

Note how the body of the function you already wrote works without modification if you explicitly name your keyword arguments after the positional varargs, making your code far more self-documenting (as well as more efficient, and with better self-checks; the clean Py3 code will error out informing you of the unrecognized argument if you pass `avrg=True` to it, while the `**kwargs` approach would require explicit checks for unknown arguments that would slow you down and bloat the code.

The closest you could get to the Py3 error-checks with minimal overhead and similar correctness/readability would be:

```
def get_event_stats(elengths, einds, *args, **kwargs):
    master_list = []
    # Unpack the recognized arguments (with default values), so kwargs left should be empty
    avg = kwargs.pop('avg', False)
    tot = kwargs.pop('tot', False)

    # If any keywords left over, they're unrecognized, raise an error
    if kwargs:
        # Arbitrarily select alphabetically first unknown keyword arg
        raise TypeError('get_event_stats() got an unexpected keyword argument {!r}'.format(min(kwargs)))

    if avg:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...
    if tot:
        for arg in args:
             do stuff...

    return master_list
```